# Image in Modal makes Image on Website disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I build a website with HTML/CSS & JavaScript and added a modal with Bootstrap 5. I changed the standard "Save changes" button of bootstrap with JavaScript to display a random image inside the modal. When the random image gets displayed inside the modal the one image i have displayed on the website disappears.

Does anyone know how to change the code so that the image on the website does not disappear while the random image gets displayed inside the modal?

I tried to change the position and the z-index of the website image in CSS but it still happened to disappear.

Comment: Help us to help you - please provide an [mre] :)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without seeing your code.You can try changing the css of the element when you open and close the modal.

```js
document.getElementById("HtmlElementId").className = "CSS-SelectorNewStyle";
```